# Laravel sail / composer require: chmod (directory attributes) error: Operation not permitted

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to run composer with Laravel Sail but getting errors:

```
$ sail composer require laravel/passport

Using version [32m^10.1[39m for [32mlaravel/passport[39m
[32m./composer.json has been updated[39m
[32mRunning composer update laravel/passport[39m
[32mLoading composer repositories with package information[39m
[32mUpdating dependencies[39m
[32mLock file operations: 13 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals[39m
  - Locking [32mdefuse/php-encryption[39m ([33mv2.2.1[39m)
  - Locking [32mfirebase/php-jwt[39m ([33mv5.2.1[39m)
  - Locking [32mlaravel/passport[39m ([33mv10.1.0[39m)
  - Locking [32mlcobucci/clock[39m ([33m2.0.0[39m)
  - Locking [32mlcobucci/jwt[39m ([33m4.1.1[39m)
  - Locking [32mleague/event[39m ([33m2.2.0[39m)
.
.
.
  - Installing [32mlcobucci/jwt[39m ([33m4.1.1[39m): Extracting archive
  - Installing [32mparagonie/random_compat[39m ([33mv9.99.100[39m): Extracting archive
  - Installing [32mdefuse/php-encryption[39m ([33mv2.2.1[39m): Extracting archive
  - Installing [32mleague/oauth2-server[39m ([33m8.2.4[39m): Extracting archive
  - Installing [32mfirebase/php-jwt[39m ([33mv5.2.1[39m): Extracting archive
  - Installing [32mlaravel/passport[39m ([33mv10.1.0[39m): Extracting archive
  0/13 [>---------------------------]   0%    [30;43mFailed to extract lcobucci/clock: (1) unzip -qq  '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/tmp-252368372558a177ddb259c3ca81856b' -d '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/29d600e9'

chmod (directory attributes) error: Operation not permitted
fchmod (file attributes) error: Operation not permitted
warning:  cannot set modif./access times for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/LICENSE.md
          Operation not permitted
fchmod (file attributes) error: Operation not permitted
warning:  cannot set modif./access times for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/README.md
          Operation not permitted
.
.
.
warning:  cannot set permissions for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/config/
          Operation not permitted
warning:  set times/attribs failed for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/config/
warning:  cannot set modif./access times for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/
          Operation not permitted
warning:  cannot set permissions for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/
          Operation not permitted
warning:  set times/attribs failed for /var/www/html/vendor/composer/43c7b0b4/laravel-passport-c2b93a7/
[39;49m
    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
    [37;41mInstall of laravel/passport failed[39;49m
```

I've basically just followed the docs for installation, then proceeded to try and install a package. Can't find anything specific to Sail online with this error. Any ideas?

Comment: can you try `$ sudo sail composer require laravel/passport`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. The error I guess is from the container, not the host.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Windows. But it's running on WSL backend (as Laravel Sail requires), if that helps.

Comment: You wrote WSL backend but you must use sail with WSL 2 backend.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's WSL 2. Strangely the container worked at first, and I was able to run a migration, now even starting the containers and running migration throws this error. I'm going to destroy all containers, volumes, restart docker and try again.It's a new installation so nothing to lose.

Comment: you tried yourappname-app_laravel.test_1  CLI in docker Hub. You can use whatever command you want. https://prnt.sc/zupfis

Comment: Yeh but I trying to run it from the host, as described in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-windows

Comment: @Martyn were you able to solve this? `require` doesn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

[image: full disk access on Terminal]

Full Disk Access to Terminal from Security & Privacy fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly the same problem while trying to install [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation) in a Docker container using the `sail` command.

Simply run this command in your application directory within your Docker container first:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The command installs all the latest required composer dependencies and updates your composer file without any of the file restrictions you encountered. In my case, it automatically ran `sail composer require laravel/breeze --dev` command for me without me having to run it manually.

After that, I only needed to run

```
sail artisan breeze:install
sail npm install
sail npm run dev
```

in order.

You can see more details in the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects).

Answer (score 1):

Worked to fix the same issue for me:
`./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

Comment: worked for me too, but doesn't make any sense :/

Comment: Well if you start containers from Docker it will start with other permission, if you start them through Sail it will start with your permissions

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was caused by enabling VirtioFS in Docker Desktop 4.6.0 for Mac. I had to disable it and go back to previous driver. However, [there're working on it](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/7#issuecomment-1066515954), so probably it'll be fixed in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL, I was able to solve the problem by enabling chmod.

Please refer to the following issue for instructions.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81#issuecomment-796798258